# Dependency Tracking Among Different Development Platforms

Tags: git, dependency-management

Anyone have ideas on how best to track dependencies among different development languages/platforms when the only common piece is Git?

My initial thought was to use some special tags in the commit messages like "DEPEND: [proj/repo-abbr]: [commit-or-tag]".

Answer (score 0):

That, uh, sounds brutal. Any particular reason you can't use [one](http://maven.apache.org/) of [the](http://www.cmake.org/) many [dependancy](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rake/0.9.2.2/frames) management [tools](https://buildr.apache.org/) in this world? Even the [oldest,](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) the [simplest](http://ant.apache.org/) and [most cranky](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) (admittedly some would say ["evil"](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1499738)) to handle dependencies during the build process, instead of at commit time?

Comment: My environment features a lot of Java and Ruby on Rails. Ant has been passable; though, not obvious or easy as the complexity of projects has increased.

Comment: Might consider [buildr.](https://buildr.apache.org/) It's more or less maven implemented in ruby. I've used it successfully, and its plugin architecture is powerful. That written it doesn't have nearly as many users as Ant or Maven, and thus can be difficult to debug without contacting the mailing list.